# Sync android data on cloud

Tags: android, onedrive

I want to sync my android app data ( database and image files ) with cloud. I an not sure of this is possible,

Prompt user for either skydrive, dropbox, google drive and depending on selection create account in 'accounts and sync' settings?

Also suppose user selected skydrive, live sdk does the authentication and returns session for that user. How can I create account in this case when login screen is not custom but its the provider's screen ? For example the way skydrive app does ?

Answer (score 0):

There're 10e+6 solutions (either incomplete or too specific).

To start with, check these OSS projects:

- MyTracks -- implements row-based syncing to Google Spreadsheets, Fusion tables, and Maps
- Financisto -- file-based sync to GDocs

For my own pet project (Wheelly) i've borrowed the first and attempted to implement 2-way sync on top of it. It's laborious and non-trivial. Certainly, it would be nice to have out of the box sqlite syncing to gdocs (or the likes); i bet there's a market for it.